# Uniform boundedness theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be subspace of $\ell^2$ which contains all 1 summable sequences. For each natural number $n$, define $T_n: V \to \mathbb R$ by $T_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. Then $T_n$ is not uniformly bounded on unit ball $\|x\|_2\leq1$.

My intuition says it has something to do with closed and bounded in infinite dimensional banach space need not be compact. But I don't know how to get a firm answer. Could you please tell me the reason? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: $T_n$ is the sequence of linear functional.

Comment: Why $T_n$ is not well defined?

Comment: Do you mean $T_nx=\sum_{k=1}^nx(k)$? (writing elements of $\ell^2$ as functions $x:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C$)

Comment: Yes. Actually I am using this site on mobile and there it is not very easy to type it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to find $x$ such that $\lVert x \rVert_2 \leq 1$ but $\lvert T_n(x) \rvert \to \infty$. Put explicitly you require $x$ to satisfy
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i^2 \leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i = \infty$$
Can you think of such $x$?

Comment: I tried to find such a $x$ but could not find it.

Comment: It's a very famous sequence with a divergent sum

Comment: Is it ${\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: Yes! Of course we need to rescale by $\left(\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-1}$ to get a norm $\leq 1$ but that's not a very important point.